# Lithium PHP integration testing - routes.php not included?

Tags: php, testing, lithium

I'm building a toy app in Lithium (PHP framework) based upon the Union of RAD's Framework project. It's all working great in the browser but when running integration tests, routes.php is not loaded, so the routing isn't working.

Here's the code I'm testing:

```
class StaffController extends \lithium\action\Controller {
    public function add() {
        $staff = Staff::create();
        if (($this->request->data) && $staff->save($this->request->data)) {
            return $this->redirect(array('Staff::view', 'args' => array($staff->id)));
        }
        return compact('staff');
}
```

My test:

```
    public function testAdd() {
            //Router::connect('/{:controller}/{:action}/{:args}');
        $request = new Request();
        $request->data = array('name' => 'Brand new user');
        $controller = new StaffController(array('request' => $request));
        /* @var $response \lithium\action\Response */
        $response = $controller->add();
        $this->assertEqual(302, $response->status['code']);
    }
```

Notice the commented out line - Router::connect('/{:controller}/{:action}/{:args}'); - if I uncomment that, it's all good.

What I'm puzzled about is why, when running in unit tests, app/config/routes.php (where I define my routes) isn't loaded. From what I can determine, app/config/bootstrap/action.php adds a filter to the "run" method of the Dispatcher which loads routes.php.

Of course, it's possible that I am totally missing the point here! I'd appreciate any guidance you can give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lithium has a `lithium\action\Dispatcher` used for http requests and a `lithium\console\Dispatcher` for console commands.

I'm assuming you are running tests from the command-line. I'm looking at the "framework" project's `app/config/bootstrap/action.php` file ([here on github](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework/blob/master/app/config/bootstrap/action.php)).

It is only including the routes.php file for the `lithium\action\Dispatcher` which is not loaded from the command-line. The `app/config/bootstrap/console.php` also doesn't include routes.php for the console.

My suggestion is to edit the `console.php` file and change the filter to look like this:

```
Dispatcher::applyFilter('run', function($self, $params, $chain) {
    Environment::set($params['request']);
    foreach (array_reverse(Libraries::get()) as $name => $config) {
        if ($name === 'lithium') {
            continue;
        }
        $file = "{$config['path']}/config/routes.php";
        file_exists($file) ? call_user_func(function() use ($file) { include $file; }) : null;
    }
    return $chain->next($self, $params, $chain);
});
```